# Lock certain cells in w2ui grid & lock icon in the cell

Tags: javascript, w2ui

I have a couple of questions regarding locking (as in not allowing user to modify) entries in w2ui grid:

1. Is there a way to lock a certain cell of an editable column?

   - I know from the documentation that I can [lock the whole grid](http://w2ui.com/web/docs/1.5/w2grid.lock) with `w2grid.lock` method.
   - I should be able to [lock one whole row](http://w2ui.com/web/docs/1.5/w2grid.records) by changing `editable: true` to `false` in the record properties.
   - I can also [lock a whole editable column](http://w2ui.com/web/docs/1.5/w2grid.columns) by changing `editable: true` to `false`.
   - But I can't think of any way to lock one particular cell.
2. How to have the yellow lock icon just like in the picture at the bottom of this [page](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/25389157-sorry-is-is-it-possible-to-paint-a-cell-of-a-different-color-independently-painting-the-entire-row)?

Thanks in advance for all the help